# Force Download an External or Internal File

Tags: php, download

**Force Download a External or Internal File like jpg**
Example **method 1** for **external** or internal file:

```
https://example.com/photos/photo.jpg/download?force=true
https://pixabay.com/images/download/wintry-69661.jpg?attachment
```

Another, this method will generate the download link

```
https://www.pexels.com/photo/2755165/download/
```

I know this **method 2**: but I need the above method 1.

```
https://download.example.com/images/download.php?file=9284.jpg
```

I have multiple codes to force download like method 2. But I need method 1.

**I'm using this PHP to force download for method 2**

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['file'])){
$fileName = basename($_GET['file']);
$filePath = '/home/download.example.com/images/'.$fileName;
if(!empty($fileName) && file_exists($filePath)){
// Define headers
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName");
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
// Read the file
readfile($filePath);
exit;
}else{
echo 'The file does not exist.';
}
}
?>
```

Thank you

Comment: Just set the `content-type` header to `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: I know about the type of code like this, and i know how to use .htaccess. But not working.

Comment: The whether a file is displayed or downloaded is up to the browser based on the returned content-type header.  You have no control over if it decides to display a save file dialog.  The application/octet-stream content type should cause the browser to download a file, but if the browser is setup to handle that mime, it will use the setup handler.  The fact that it is "not working" doesn't help anyone figure out why.  Your example shows "Content-Type: image/jpeg" which would display the image in the browser.